# Multiple GPU tf Estimator Object Detection

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, object-detection, tensorflow-estimator

Recently (July 13th 2018) TensorFlow Object Detection API moved from slim-based training to Estimator-based training.

I previously used multiple GPUs by setting `--num_clones=N --ps_tasks=1` while running the (now) `/legacy/train.py` script. However, now I can't seem to figure out how to run on multiple GPUs with this new estimator-based training. This functionality wasn't removed was it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I found out that they actually removed multi gpu support and recommend using the legacy code for now :/ no idea why.